# How do you sort Paired Data on Spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

How do i sort my data to produce a sorted paired row + sorted position outcome?

Desired Outcome:

| Row | Position |
| --- | --- |
| R1 | A01 |
| R2 | A01 |
| R1 | A02 |
| R2 | A02 |
| R1 | A03 |
| R2 | A03 |
| R3 | A01 |
| R4 | A01 |
| R3 | A02 |
| R4 | A02 |
| R3 | A03 |
| R4 | A03 |

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your columns with mouse (or CTRL-A to select everything, if this is the only entry in the whole sheet)
2. Select "Filter" from Data menu: first row of data (labels) present a new arrow sign: click it and it gives the sort menu
3. select anything that suits you and it will be sorted in a paired way for all selected cells

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to create a sorting group. You can use this formula:

```
=ROUNDUP(INT(RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-1))/2,0)
```

Like this:

[image]

You can then use the sort dialog configured like this:

[image]

If you want to change it so that you are sorting three of the values in the Row column at a time, you would change the denominator in the formula to 3, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!